# App using Google Play Game Services Crashing right away

Tags: android-logcat, google-play-games

I dual booted my computer to Linux and I copied all my project files over to Eclipse in Linux and I am getting these errors.

```
>07-04 23:23:17.980: W/PopupManager(6781): You have not specified a View to use as content >view for popups. Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly in >future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your content view.
>07-04 23:23:17.990: W/art(6781): Failed to find ELF magic in >/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.odex: dey
>07-04 23:23:18.000: W/art(6781): Failed to find ELF magic in >/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.odex: dey
>07-04 23:23:18.000: W/art(6781): Failed to find ELF magic in >/system/framework/com.google.android.ble.odex: dey
>07-04 23:23:18.100: W/ResourceType(6781): Failure getting entry for 0x7f06000d (t=5 e=13) >in package 0 (error -75)
>07-04 23:23:18.100: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6781): The Google Play services resources were >not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
>07-04 23:23:18.150: I/Adreno-EGL(6781): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM >Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
>07-04 23:23:18.170: D/OpenGLRenderer(6781): Enabling debug mode 0
>07-04 23:23:18.570: D/AndroidRuntime(6781): Shutting down VM
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
v07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781): Process: com.cs407project.cardgameswithfriends, >PID: 6781
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal >developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at >com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.b(Unknown Source)
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at >com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.a(Unknown Source)
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at >com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$b.ec(Unknown Source)
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at >com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at >android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at >android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native >Method)
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>07-04 23:23:18.570: E/AndroidRuntime(6781):    at >com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>07-04 23:27:40.990: I/Process(6781): Sending signal. PID: 6781 SIG: 9
```

This error occurs before onCreate() gets called. I have BaseGameUtils and google-play-service_lib imported as libraries and they're both in my main program's build path. The google-play-services_lib is copied from the SDK, so it's not being referenced from there.

If someone can offer advice in general about how to/what to read in the logcat I would appreciate it. I always feel like I'm reading randoms bits at the top or bottom and trying things until it works.

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely a result of having not set com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID in the AndroidManifest. See Step 3 of [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart).

Try adding this to AndroidManifest.xml, inside the application element:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
   android:value="@string/app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Where @string/app_id refers to your app's game services id in the Google Play Developer Console. [This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-game-services-achievements--cms-20591) tutorial on implementing achievements walks you through the whole process.